# circle collision causes circle to go supersonic

Tags: java

can anyone tell me why the circles i draw are getting stuck on each other or going super fast and flying off the window. all i want is for the circles to bounce off each other, but instead they get stuck 1/3 of the time, accelerate drastically another 1/3 of the time and only bounce the other 1/3. sorry if its messy, i've been trying a lot of different ideas and it kind of got out of hand. code uses maths that i got from gist.github/christopher4lis/f9ccb589ee8ecf751481f05a8e59b1dc. its horribly done but its the best i can do for now.
Please let me know if there is any other code that you need to help fix this.

```
   public void bounce() {
        collision = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            for (int a = 0; a < size; a++) {
                float xVelDiff = dots[i][2] - dots[a][2];
                float yVelDiff = dots[i][3] - dots[a][3];
                float xDist = dots[i][0] - dots[a][0];
                float yDist = dots[i][1] - dots[a][1];
                if (xVelDiff * xDist + yVelDiff * yDist <= 0) {
                    angle = (float) -Math.atan2(dots[a][0] - dots[i][0], dots[a][1] - dots[i][1]);

                    float m1 = dots[i][7];
                    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(m1).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                    m1 = bd.floatValue();
                    float m2 = dots[a][7];
                    float[] u1 = rotate(dots[i][2], dots[i][3], (float) angle);
                    float[] u2 = rotate(dots[a][2], dots[a][3], (float) angle);
                    float[] v1 = new float[2];
                    v1[0] = u1[0] * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u2[0] * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2);
                    v1[1] = u1[1];
                    float[] v2 = new float[2];
                    v2[0] = u2[0] * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u1[0] * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2);
                    v2[1] = u2[1];

                    float[] vFinal1 = rotate(v1[0], v1[1], (float) -angle);
                    float[] vFinal2 = rotate(v2[0], v2[1], (float) -angle);

                    if (a != i && !(dots[a][0] == 0 && dots[a][1] == 0)) {
                        boolean thisCollision = (dots[a][0] - dots[i][0]) * (dots[a][0] - dots[i][0]) + (dots[a][1] - dots[i][1]) * (dots[a][1] - dots[i][1]) <= (dots[a][4] + dots[i][4]) * (dots[a][4] + dots[i][4]);
//                    System.out.println("collision: "+collision+" i="+i+" a="+a);
                        if (thisCollision) {
                            System.out.println(vFinal2[0] + " " + vFinal2[1]);
                            collision = true;
                            dots[i][2] = vFinal1[0];
                            dots[i][3] = vFinal1[1];
                            dots[a][2] = vFinal2[0];
                            dots[a][3] = vFinal2[1];
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public float[] rotate(float velocityX, float velocityY, float angle) {
        float x1 = (float) (velocityX * Math.cos(angle) - velocityY * Math.sin(angle));
        float y1 = (float) (velocityX * Math.cos(angle) - velocityY * Math.sin(angle));
        float vel[] = new float[2];
        vel[0] = x1;
        vel[1] = y1;
        return vel;
    }
```

Comment: What are your starting conditions?

Comment: Not yet covered it all, but definitely do your for loops non-overlapping: `for (int a = i + 1; a < size; a++) ` You are making a lot of calculations that make no sense in case of coinciding points and just at the very end have a check `i != a`. Actually some functions should even throw in case of `a == i`

Comment: what do you mean by starting conditions? if you mean the values of the dots array, they are randomized.

Comment: I mean the A-for cycle.  I already gave you what think better definition will be in my first comment